# Given windows of start and stop times for each object, how can I count how many objects were on for each second?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

TurnedOn = pd.Series([1000.4,1200.5,1550.1,500.3])
TurnedOff = pd.Series([1400.2,1600.8,1570.3,74500.6])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[TurnedOn,TurnedOff]).T
df.index = ['OBJ1','OBJ2','OBJ3','OBJ4']
```

[image: dataframe]

I want to get a time based count in seconds throughout the day of how many lights were on at a 0.1 second sampling rate.

I've tried doing this by making a large dataframe from 0 to 864000 (seconds per day times 10), and setting each object true for each 0.1 second in the time window of between Turned on and Turned off and then counting them, but this is horribly inefficient for large dataframes.

Is there something in python that I can use to count how many lights are on each second?

For instance, the output would be:

500.3-1000.4: 1 light

1000.4-1200.5: 2 lights

1200.5 - 1400.2: 3 lights

1400.2-1550.1: 2 lights

1550.1-1570.3: 3 lights

1570.3-1600.8: 2 lights

1600.8-74500.6: 1 light

Comment: Split the list in two, start times and end times, combined back again into a single list. Sort the list by time. Keep a counter, increment it when you see a start and decrement it when you see an end.

Answer (score 1):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

TurnedOn = pd.Series([1000.4, 1200.5, 1550.1, 500.3])
TurnedOff = pd.Series([1400.2, 1600.8, 1570.3, 74500.6])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[TurnedOn, TurnedOff]).T
df.columns = ["TurnedOn", "TurnedOff"]

print(df)
# Output

   TurnedOn  TurnedOff
0    1000.4     1400.2
1    1200.5     1600.8
2    1550.1     1570.3
3     500.3    74500.6
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```py
# Prep data
df = (
    df.unstack()
    .reset_index()
    .drop(columns="level_1")
    .rename(columns={"level_0": "status", 0: "start"})
)
df = df.sort_values(by="start", ignore_index=True)
df["end"] = df["start"].shift(-1)

# Count how many lights are simultaneously on
df["num_lights_on"] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x["status"] == "TurnedOn" else -1, axis=1)
df["num_lights_on"] = df["num_lights_on"].cumsum()

# Cleanup
df = df.reindex(["start", "end", "num_lights_on"], axis=1).dropna()
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output

    start      end  num_lights_on
0   500.3   1000.4              1
1  1000.4   1200.5              2
2  1200.5   1400.2              3
3  1400.2   1550.1              2
4  1550.1   1570.3              3
5  1570.3   1600.8              2
6  1600.8  74500.6              1
```